# Mockito returns FileNotFoundException although file is there

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to run a test on a newly Spring Boot created service class. StringWriter content is regular XML with a few lines of tags named 'transaction'.

**PrepareExcelServiceTest**.class

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PrepareExcelServiceTest {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrepareExcelService.class);

    @Test
    public void testPrepareExcelService() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        PrepareExcelService prepareExcelService = new PrepareExcelService();
        StringWriter xmlStringWriter = new StringWriter();

        Source source = new StreamSource("./view/xml/0_dummy.xml");
        xmlStringWriter.write(source.toString());

        prepareExcelService.prepareDocument(xmlStringWriter);
    }
}
```

**PrepareExcelService**.class

```
@Service
public class PrepareExcelService {

    private HSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private HSSFSheet spreadsheet;

    public void prepareDocument(StringWriter xmlStringWriter) throws IOException,
                                                                            SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        workbook = setupWorkBook();
        spreadsheet = setupSheet(workbook);

        Document document = parseXMLStringWriter(xmlStringWriter);
        fillContent(document, spreadsheet);

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("TestExcelFile.xls"));
        workbook.write(output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }

    private HSSFWorkbook setupWorkBook() {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
        cellStyle.setIndention((short)4);
        cellStyle.setWrapText(true);

        HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)24);
        font.setFontName("Courier New");
        font.setItalic(false);
        cellStyle.setFont(font);

        return workbook;
    }

    private HSSFSheet setupSheet(HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        HSSFSheet spreadSheet = workbook.createSheet("spreadSheet");
        return spreadSheet;
    }

    private Document parseXMLStringWriter(StringWriter xmlStringWriter) throws ParserConfigurationException,
                                                                                            IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        return builder.parse(xmlStringWriter.toString());
    }

    private void fillContent (Document document, HSSFSheet spreadSheet) {
        HSSFRow row = spreadSheet.createRow(0);
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) 1);

        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("transaction");
        HSSFRow rowOne = spreadSheet.createRow(1);

        cell.setCellValue("Spreadsheet Header Row");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    cell = rowOne.createCell((short) 0);
                    cell.setCellValue("transaction");
                    cell = rowOne.createCell((short) 1);
                    cell.setCellValue(((Element) (nodeList.item(0))).getElementsByTagName("transaction").item(0)
                                                                                        .getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While testing this service I get the following exception although the file is there and other services interact with it correctly through StringWriter.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...\javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource@4439f31e (The system cannot find the file specified)

    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:623)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:177)
    at ee.estcard.repgen.service.PrepareExcelService.parseXMLStringWriter(PrepareExcelService.java:78)
    at ee.estcard.repgen.service.PrepareExcelService.prepareDocument(PrepareExcelService.java:39)
    at ee.estcard.repgen.service.PrepareExcelServiceTest.testPrepareExcelService(PrepareExcelServiceTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluate(JUnitRule.java:16)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I think the problem lies in my incorrect usage of StringWriter, but due to my rookie knowledge of Java I am still unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I doubt the `StringWriter` is a good type to use for a method signature for transporting "string-content". There are many alternatives, use a pointer (i.e. URI, Path, File) to the content or some consumable representation of the character content (Reader, InputStream, InputSourc) or the content itself (String).

But assume, you did that on purpose:

The `DocumentBuilder`'s `parse()` method accepts:

- an `InputSource`
- an `InputStream`
- a URI-String pointing to a file

Your StringWriter or better, the result of it's `toString()` method is neither of them. So you need to convert the `StringWriter`'s buffer content into any of those types.

Probably the easiest would be to

```
new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStringWriter.toString()))
```

so the method may look like:

```
private Document parseXMLStringWriter(StringWriter xmlStringWriter) throws ParserConfigurationException,
                                                                                        IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStringWriter.toString())));
}
```

Now you're able to parse the string contained in the writer. But still, the content is wrong.

The `StreamSource`'s `toString()` method creates an object reference string, but does not produce the content of the file referenced by the StreamSource. Instead, you need to fetch the content of the file.

Probably the easiest way to get the file content into a String is

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file")));
```

(ignores the encoding of the file)

This should get your test running. But again, don't use the StringWriter at all.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. The reason I am using the StringWriter is that it is used in my other class in order to process it through an XSL transformation. The main problem is that I cannot create an XML file physically. The data has to be kept in memory, hence the StringFormat. Is there a way to make the content correct using the StringWriter?

Answer (score 2):

No your problem is related to how you use `StreamSource`, indeed calling `source.toString()` won't give you the content of the source as you seem to expect but something like `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource@4439f31e` as you can see in your stack trace.

Simply get rid of your `StringWriter` and use a `InputSource` in your code to fix your code but also to make it much more flexible since using `InputSource` is an open door to many different type of sources, moreover loading the content of a file is not a good practice and should be avoided because if the file is too big you could face OOME if it cannot fit into the heap.

**In `PrepareExcelServiceTest`**

```
PrepareExcelService prepareExcelService = new PrepareExcelService();
InputSource source = new InputSource("./view/xml/0_dummy.xml");
prepareExcelService.prepareDocument(source);
```

**In the method `parseXMLStringWriter` to be renamed**

```
private Document parseXML(InputSource source) throws ParserConfigurationException,
    IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    return builder.parse(source);
}
```

**In the method `prepareDocument`**

```
public void prepareDocument(InputSource source) throws IOException,
    SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    ...

    Document document = parseXML(source);

    ...
}
```

Comment: problem is, `DocumentBuilder` does not accept a `java.xml.transform.Source` as parameter